# Error when adding a controller in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was following Entity framework tutorial in Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#main

Here I've done up to **Set up EF to use a SQL Server Express LocalDB database**.And in **Creating a Student Controller and Views** section when I tried to add a controller using *MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework* (as mentioned in the tutorial), I'm getting an error saying

> Attempting to install version '6.1.1' of 'EntityFramework' but the project already includes a different version. Skipping...

I tried reinstalling Entity Framework using the console, but still, it doesn't solve the problem. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try to uninstall Entity Framework an then reinstall it

> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
>
> Install-Package EntityFramework

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in Package manager console:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

then close visual studio and delete entity framework floder in `packages.config`

again open Visual Studio and run this command:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently run into the same error.

Resolved it by uninstalling all the ef core packages through Nuget package manager and re-installing them with the latest stable version (5.0.9)

I have re-installed following ef core packages

- EntityFrameworkCore
- EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Note: Don't forget to rebuild the solution

See below screenshot

[image]